# How to access elements when looping over JavaScript multi-dimensional array with jQuery's .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, jwplayer

I'm working on a dynamic jwplayer video player on a website and am having trouble getting the preview image to be dynamic. I'm trying to use a multidimensional array to keep things lean but can't seem to get the second value (the preview image) to be included in the loop.

```
videos = [];
videos.push([ "v1", video1, videoThumb1 ]);
videos.push([ "v2", video2, videoThumb2 ]); 
videos.push([ "v3", video3, videoThumb3 ]); 
videos.push([ "v4", video4, videoThumb4 ]); 
videos.push([ "v5", video5, videoThumb5 ]); 

$.each(videos, function(i, v, p) {
    jwplayer(v[0]).setup({
        file: v[1],
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        image: p[1]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function in the each loop takes two arguments, the index and the item.

This item in this case is each of your video entries.

so v[0] us the name
v[1] is the video
and v[2] is the videoThumb

```
videos = [];
videos.push([ "v1", video1, videoThumb1 ]);
videos.push([ "v2", video2, videoThumb2 ]); 
videos.push([ "v3", video3, videoThumb3 ]); 
videos.push([ "v4", video4, videoThumb4 ]); 
videos.push([ "v5", video5, videoThumb5 ]); 

$.each(videos, function(i, v) {
    jwplayer(v[0]).setup({
        file: v[1],
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        image: v[2]
    });
});
```

Comment: You sir are my favorite. Worked like a charm, and I have a much better understanding as to why. Thanks!